# Handling success and failure when retrieving product information

Tags: javascript, error-handling, angular.js, controller, callback

I've got an Angular controller where I have two functions that are repeated inside two functions:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.purchases.products' )
        .controller( 'ReadProductController', ReadProductController );

    ReadProductController.$inject = [ '$scope', 'ReadProductFactory' ];

    function ReadProductController( $scope, ReadProductFactory ) {

        /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;

        vm.products          = {};
        vm.product           = {};
        vm.getProductsList   = getProductsList;
        vm.getProductDetails = getProductDetails;

        function getProductsList( columnOrder, sortOrder ) {

            var data = {
                columnOrder: columnOrder,
                sortOrder: sortOrder
            };

            ReadProductFactory.listProducts( data, success, fail );

            //The following are the callbacks funcs but they repeat 
            //for the getProductDetails func too, should i set them global?
            function success( products ) {
                vm.products = products;
            }

            function fail( error ) {
                console.log( error );
            }
        }

        function getProductDetails( id ) {

            var data = {
                id: id
            };

            ReadProductFactory.detailProduct( data, success, fail );

            function success( product ) {
                vm.product = product;
            }

            function fail( error ) {
                console.log( error );
            }

        }

    }

})();
```

The above is the controller of a Product Listing view, i've tried to take rest logic to a factory, what i feel is that my code is not completely DRY because of the callback functions, maybe you'll understand better what i've tried to do with the factory code, here it is:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.purchases.products' )
        .factory( 'ReadProductFactory', ReadProductFactory );

    ReadProductFactory.$inject = [ 'Restangular' ];

    function ReadProductFactory( Restangular ) {

        return {
            detailProduct: detailProduct,
            listProducts: listProducts
        };

        function detailProduct( data, success, fail ) {

            Restangular
                .one( '/purchases/products/', data.id )
                .all( '/detail' )
                .getList()
                .then( success, fail );

        }

        function listProducts( data, success, fail ) {


            Restangular
                .all( '/purchases/products/list' )
                .getList()
                .then( success, fail );

        }

    }

})();
```

Somes have told me to use promises instead of callback, how could i do that?
Also, is it good practice to declare empty arrays as I've done?

Answer (score 1):

First, your controller is written weirdly. It could be simplified into:

```
// Since we're inlining everything, we don't need to wrap it in IIFE.
// Also, `readProductController` isn't a good name. Controllers are things,
// nouns, not verbs.
angular.module( 'app.purchases.products' ).controller('ProductController',[

  // A controller accepts either a function with implicit dependencies based on
  // argument names, or an array of dependency names, and whose last element
  // is the controller function.
  '$scope', 'productFactory'
, function(

  // I've read somewhere that factories and services should be named with first
  // letter as small since we're not exporting a constructor. Reserve Capital
  // names for things that return a constructor function.
  $scope, productFactory
){

  // Not sure why `vm` exactly. It doesn't tell me what it is. Name it something
  // meaningful, like `controller`.
  var controller = this;
  controller.products = {};
  controller.product = {};

  // You can simply inline the functions. No need for the indirection.
  this.getProductsList = function(columnOrder, sortOrder){

    // Promises are simply just objects that hold state for an async operation.
    // They still accept "callbacks" via the `then` method they provide.
    productFactory.getProducts({
      columnOrder: columnOrder,
      sortOrder: sortOrder
    }).then(function(products){
      controller.products = products;
    }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  this.getProductDetails = function(id){
    productFactory.getProductDetails({
      id: id
    }).then(function(product){
      controller.product = product;
    }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  };


}]);
```

We can do the same with your service

```
// `readProductFactory` isn't really a good factory name. Factories are things
// that create things. They're not actions, so drop the read. It's just
// productFactory starting now.
angular.module('app.purchases.products').factory('productFactory', [
  'Restangular',
function(
  Restangular
){
  return {

    // Functions are "actions", verbs, commands. They should be named in a
    // "do something to that something" manner, like `getList`, or `sendMail`
    getProducts: function(data){

      // Restangular appears to already return a promise (because you "then'ed")
      // All we have to do is just return that promise to the controller so that
      // it listens with `then`.
      return Restangular.all( '/purchases/products/list' ).getList()
    },
    getProductDetails: function(data){

      // Doing the same
      return Restangular.one( '/purchases/products/', data.id ).all( '/detail' ).getList()

    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: The "Wierd" code is the [code style introduced by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), `vm` stands for **View-Model**, the reason why i named the controller `ReadProductsController` it's because i'm trying to keep the singleton concept, so i decided to create a single Create, Read, Update, Delete, since they all are attached to different Views, but maybe i could create several services and keep one single `ProductController`, thanks Joseph